# about some characterisation of non-measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory

We know that a set E is measurable if and only if characteristics function of E is measurable function. So if N is non measurable set then characteristics function of N is non measurable function. 
My question is that are the all non-measurable functions?
( yeah, by adding or by other algebraic operation of some nice function with this characteristics fns gives also non-measurable function. I am asking whether we can get a non-measurable fn without this characteristics fns kind of stuffs!)

Comment: Please read my complete question @fonfonx. Can I get get a non-measurable function which don't include a characteristics function of a non-measurable set?

Comment: Take a nonmeasurable set $N$, define $f$ to vanish on $N$ and to be anything on $N^{c}$, except for values of absolute value less than some $\epsilon$. The preimage of the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ is $N$, which is nonmeasurable, so $f$ is nonmeasurable.

Comment: This also some sort of characteristics function of N-complement( N-complement is also a non-measurable set). Encouraging more answers.

Comment: It need not be a characteristic function on $N^{c}$. Any value is permitted provided absolute value greater than $\epsilon$. (actually any value is also permitted on $N$, provided absolute value less than $\epsilon$)

Comment: The value is fixed say "a". Then it is the a* chi(N-complement). Isn't it? May be I am wrong. Correct me.

Comment: no, the constant need not be fixed. If $x$, $y$, $z$, $\dotsc$ are in $N^{c}$, define $f(x)=1$, $f(y)=2$, $f(z)=3$, etc. or anything you like, provided these values are $>\epsilon$. Likewise, if $a$, $b$, $c$, are in $N$, define $f(a)=\epsilon/2$, $f(b)=\epsilon/3$, $f(c)=\epsilon/4$, etc. provided these values are $<\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok. Now I got your point. It was my fault. Yeah that is also working. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's about this:

Let $S$ be a non-measurable subset of $(0,+\infty)$.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x, \, x\in S\\-x, \, x\notin S\end{cases}$$

But notice that $\{x : f(x) \ge 0\}=S \sqcup (-\infty,0]$, which is not a measurable set. Thus $f$ is not measurable.